# Checking status of bootloader

Tags: android

Theres an app on OEM Android phones called service menu its reached by dialing a certain code, this gives the user information about the device and information about the status of the bootloader.

How do I get this information, is there a file in /proc that I can read to get this, or is there a kernel api

thanks

Comment: Its not necessarily on all phones.  WHat you are describing is called a USSD code, and their existance changes by model, oem, and carrier.  You cannot trust that any of them exists on any particular device.  There is also no API to make USSD calls or extract information from a USSD response.  Now if you're looking for specific information, you need to tell us exactly what you want, not "from this app service menu" because that app won't exist on all devices or have the same info if it does exist.

Comment: I don't need the USSD Code, I just would like to know, how these apps get information like the status of the bootloader, it receives some of this from build.prop, I want to be able to find out the status of the bootloader @GabeSechan